# Copy and pasting absolute positions for animations

Tags: animation

I'm animating at the moment and while I can use Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V to copy and paste positions in the timeline, these are positions relative to parent objects.

Essentially I'm rotating the root of my model, but I want one part of my model to remain still.
e.g. I rotate the root 90 degrees, rotating my entire model, but I want to set just a leg back to its exact unrotated position.

Is there a way to copy and paste an objects absolute position, regardless of parent position? Right now I am having to move the leg in each keyframe to the original position, which makes it jiggle slightly as I can't get it exact.

Once the animation is finished I want to remove the root rotation from the frames, so it would be far harder to simply apply the rotation to everything but the leg, as I'd have to remove that rotation from every component of every frame after finishing, accounting for any additional rotation applied as part of the animation itself.

Comment: hmm, no clue of what your trying to do here.
There is inverse kinematics, but not sure if that's where you after.
Something that might work is working with empties with some nested parenting so they move relative from eachother. Add an extra root parrent and remove it later.as for your last paragraph.